# Wired Connection not working on 18.04(LTS). Please Help

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, iptables

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s25:
    flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 28:d2:44:44:0a:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13959  bytes 1516430 (1.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6983  bytes 2019189 (2.0 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xf3900000-f3920000   

lo:
    flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 14596  bytes 1471483 (1.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 14596  bytes 1471483 (1.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

My wifi connection works perfectly fine when I connect but wired connection shows connected symbol but doesn't work. Even my wired connection has no IP address. For the above 2 config files people have posted various things online but I don't know which setting will work in my situation. I was actually trying to install cuckoo sandbox previously which messed up my `iptables`. I had to reset my `iptables` as well. Don't know if something related to that is causing this problem.

Comment: Past the text, don't use pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for editing my question. When I am running the network diagnostics, I am getting the following error- https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w4TVX2hhhQ/

Comment: Why did you run the (first) command as super-user? That's both unnecessary and leads to the observed problem (unless you run all of the three commands as super-user). Please try again without `sudo`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Still error I guess. Please check - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pscvkvnNxQ/

Comment: Now that you created a root-owned file `wireless-info` by the use of `sudo` you can't overwrite it or change its access permissions as a regular user. Please remove it as super-user (`sudo rm wireless-info`) and try again.

Comment: Ok it worked successfully. Check the results - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Fk6vPdHWBf/